# ReactJs Todo List push state

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have written the start of a todo list in reactjs and was looking to improve the functionality of how the todos are added to the state. Currently I am concat(ting) the value in put to an array which is in the state, then splicing off the selected li element. It seems to be a bit buggy when you add the first todo.  Should i be using reacts immutability helpers to acheive this? Seems overkill to add another thing that can be acheived in plain js.

```
//Input component
const Input = props => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        className="form-control"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.update}
        type="text"
      />
      <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={props.handleClick}>
        Add Todo
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
//display list of todos
const Displaytodo = (props) => {
  const todolist = props.todo;
  const listItems = todolist.map((todo, index) =>
    <li
      className={
       props.highlight ? 'list-unstyled todoItem highlight' : 'list-unstyled todoItem '
      }
      key={index}>
      {todo}
      <div
        onClick={props.removeTodo.bind(this, index)}
        className="removeTodo">
        <i className="fa fa-trash" />
      </div>
      <div onClick={props.changeHighlight.bind(this,index)} className="checkTodo">
        <i className="fa fa-check-circle" onClick={props.highlight} />
      </div>
    </li>
  );

  return <ul className="todos">{listItems}</ul>;
};
//controlled state component
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { text: "Hello", todo: [], highlight: false };
  }
  update(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }
  handleClick() {
    const text = this.state.text;
    if (text.length > 0) {
      this.setState(
        { todo: this.state.todo.concat(text), text: "", highlight: false },
        function() {
          console.log(this.state.todo);
        }
      );
    } else {
      alert("please enter something");
    }
  }
  removeTodo(e) {
    this.state.todo.splice(e, 1);
    this.setState({ todo: this.state.todo });
  }

  changeHighlight(index, e) {
    const highlight = this.state.highlight;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      highlight: !prevState.highlight
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">

          <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div className="wrapper">
              <h1>Todo List</h1>

              <Input
                value={this.state.text}
                update={this.update.bind(this)}
                handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
              />
              <Displaytodo
                removeTodo={this.removeTodo.bind(this)}
                todo={this.state.todo}
                changeHighlight={this.changeHighlight.bind(this)}
                highlight={this.state.highlight}
              />
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById("app");

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, app);
```

https://codepen.io/mhal12/pen/MomWVg

Also when the user clicks the green tick, it will highlight the row by toggling class 'highlight' off and on, but in console it giving an error. which links to

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=94&args[]=onClick&args[]=boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `onClick` on `<i className="fa fa-check-circle" onClick={props.highlight} />`.

As for the highlighting on each `todo`, it's a bit more complex. You have to have an `id` on each `todo`, and then pass the `id` to the `changeHighlight` function. You have to remove highlight from global state, and assign a `highlight` boolean on each `todo`. Then you have to display `todos` accordingly.

Same stuff for the `removeTodo` function, you pass in an `id` to remove it in the parent component.

Here's the full code :

```
const Input = props => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        className="form-control"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.update}
        type="text"
      />
      <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={props.handleClick}>
        Add Todo
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
const Displaytodo = (props) => {
  const changeHighlight = function(id) {
    props.changeHighlight(id);
  }

  const removeTodo = function(id) {
    props.removeTodo(id);
  }

  const todolist = props.todo;
  const listItems = todolist.map((todo, index) =>
    <li
      className={
       todo.highlight ? 'list-unstyled todoItem highlight' : 'list-unstyled todoItem '
      }
      key={todo.id}>
      {todo.text}
      <div
        onClick={removeTodo.bind(event, todo.id)}
        className="removeTodo">
        <i className="fa fa-trash" />
      </div>
      <div onClick={changeHighlight.bind(event, todo.id)} className="checkTodo">
        <i className="fa fa-check-circle" />
      </div>
    </li>
  );

  return <ul className="todos">{listItems}</ul>;
};
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {text: "Hello", todo: []};
  }
  update(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }
  handleClick() {
    const text = this.state.text;
    if (text.length > 0) {
      this.setState(
        { todo: this.state.todo.concat({
          id: this.state.todo.length + 1,
          text: this.state.text,
          highlight: false
        }), text: ""},
        function() {
          console.log(this.state.todo);
        }
      );
    } else {
      alert("Please enter something");
    }
  }
  removeTodo(id) {
    let todos = this.state.todo;

    for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
      let todo = todos[i];
      if (todo.id == id) {
        todos.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    this.setState({ todo: todos });
  }

  changeHighlight(id) {    
    let todos = this.state.todo;

    for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
      let todo = todos[i];
      if (todo.id == id) {
        todos[i].highlight = !todos[i].highlight;
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      todo : todos
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">

          <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div className="wrapper">
              <h1>Todo List</h1>

              <Input
                value={this.state.text}
                update={this.update.bind(this)}
                handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
              />
              <Displaytodo
                removeTodo={this.removeTodo.bind(this)}
                todo={this.state.todo}
                changeHighlight={this.changeHighlight.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById("app");

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, app);
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, Totally missed that onclick, where i orginally had them!  Moving highlight out of global state works perfectly thanks.

Comment: No problem. Please mark answer as solution if it solved  your problem :)

Comment: I have applied your suggested changes to my code, I have also noticed my splice function is actually removing the first item in the array instead of selected item. Check my codepen for example, any help much appreciated..  ps. dont have rep to upvote yet :(

Comment: Edited my answer :) You can still mark my answer as the right one by clicking the checkmark !

Comment: Thanks, i was along the same lines before you posted this, working perfectly now.